# RAID system with external hardrives

Tags: hard-drive, storage, raid

I have a few external ssd hardrives (My Passport, in my case). I would like to integrate them within a system that provides reliability in case of failure, by producing redundant information across the devices, seamlessly from the User point of view.

What would be a product worth considering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's clarify one thing: **RAID is not the same as backup.** Building a RAID array out of several (presumably USB) external drives would have many drawbacks. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/505840/which-configuration-will-yield-the-best-throughput-for-a-usb-raid-array) I asked a while back for the explanation. I suspect what you really want is passive and seamless disk/data backup in which case OS X's built-in Time Machine works great. And if you have Mountain Lion it is capable of using all of your external drives to store the backups.

Comment: are you saying that with TM, if I have 2 or more drives, it will take care of creating redundant data?

Comment: @Bob I am saying that on Mountain Lion Time Machine will spread the backups across both drives.  I do not know the algorithm used to do the spreading. I just know that TM can use more than one drive.